# How the gemfile will be maintained, as a common one for iOS and Android in react-native app

Tags: android, ios, react-native, gemfile, gemfile.lock

How the Gemfile will be maintained, as a common one for iOS and Android or not. I am using react-native app

I have setup fastlane there it crated a Gemfile and it is inside the android folder.

Then an another Gemfile will create in the root folder of my react-native app.

Can anyone let me know this? Can I use single Gemfile for android and iOS which is available in the root directory